# django pagination not showing page numbers

Tags: django, pagination

My view:

```
class HospitalAppointmentView(ListView):
model = DoctorAppointment
template_name = "doctor_appointment_list.html"
paginate_by = 5

def get(self, request, pk, username, hdpk, **kwargs):
    self.pk = pk
    self.username = username
    self.hdpk = hdpk
    return super(HospitalAppointmentView, self).get(request, pk, username, hdpk, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HospitalAppointmentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['appointments'] = DoctorAppointment.objects.filter(hospital__id=self.pk, doctor__id=self.hdpk).order_by("-appointment_date")
    context['today'] = today
    return context
```

And my template:

```
{% for appointment in appointments %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{appointment.appointment_date}}</td>

    <td>{{appointment.first_name}} &nbsp;{{appointment.middle_name}} &nbsp; {{appointment.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{appointment.user}}</td>

</tr>

{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
```

When I do this it displays the page no but dont paginate the data.. It shows all the list. It should be showing only 5 value but showing all the value.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appointments should be a Pagination object. Currently you are sending a queryset.

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/ for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the appointments in get_context_data, you should override `get_queryset`.

```
class HospitalAppointmentView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return DoctorAppointment.objects.filter(
            hospital__id=self.pk,
            doctor__id=self.hdpk).order_by("-appointment_date")
```

Also, change the template variable you access to `object_list`:

```
{% for appointment in object_list %}
```